# copying text from ms word to wordpress post appears weird

Tags: text, encoding

someone has send me an article for blog post it is an msword file
when i copy and paste the text in my wordpress blog post the preview shows like this

[image]

some characters appear small , some big, 
i tried copy pasting the text in notepad and then to the post editing area but issue does not solve
the issue does not appear if i type the text myself but is quite a long article
i think there might be some issue with encoding so i tried converting to ANSI 
then i lose characters and the converted text shows like

```
    but th? ?r?bl?m ??n ?t?ll ?r???. Wh?n ?t d???, ??u need t? kn?w
    wh?t ??u'r? looking ?t and come u? w?th ways of und?r?t?nd?ng her,
    and tr? to respect h?r ?r???n?? ?? th?t she can also respect ??u.
```

any idea how to fix this? ir what to ask from the post sender to do to their article, so that i can use it for copy pasting?
Thanks

EDIT:
....tried the solution suggested by David....

this is what it looks like at back end

[image]

but preview still shows same, cannot attach more than 2 images

any leads?

Comment: There is a button in the visual editor to paste the Microsoft's formatted text. If you used this, what text encoding do you use for the WordPress site? Do you use a custom or the default system font set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Disable it in your Word, go to `Word` > `Preferences` > `General` then clear the check for Include formatted text in Clipboard. This is a
   global setting by the way so any cut/copy will render un-formatted
   text.
2. Click on this icon:

[image]

[image]

3. Use notepad, copy the content to notepad then copy it from notepad
   to WordPress.

Comment: tried all that you suggested
I am updating my question with screenshot of what i tried.. the same error! :(

Comment: can you copy paste the text here in a comment

Comment: sure there you go

but thе рrоblеm саn ѕtіll аrіѕе. Whеn іt dоеѕ, уоu need tо knоw whаt уоu'rе looking аt аnd come uр wіth ways of undеrѕtаndіng her, and trу to respect hеr рrеѕеnсе ѕо thаt she can also respect уоu.

Comment: okay, that looks good, have you tried option 1 and 3?

Comment: yes I did , I edited my original question to attach screenshot of method 2, and yes i tried 3 too...